# HTTP Put with Rails App using iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, httprequest, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to connect to a Rails server using an iOS app.  I'm running into issues when I try to do a PUT request with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)addSpin:(id)sender{

    NSString *newSpinURLString = [spinBaseURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"/new?auth_token=%@", auth_token];
    NSDictionary *spinDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: (NSString *)_setID, @"project_id", nil];
    NSLog(@"spinDict %@", spinDict);
    NSDictionary *holderDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:spinDict, @"spin", nil];
    NSLog(@"holderDict %@", holderDict);
    NSData *holder = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:holderDict options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"adding new spin on server %@", newSpinURLString);
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:newSpinURLString];
    NSURL *newSetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    // send JSON request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL: newSetURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    // set the request headers
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:holder];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){
            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData: data
                                          options:kNilOptions
                                          error:&error];
            newSpinID= [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSLog(@"newSpinID: %@", newSpinID);
        }
    }];

}
```

This is the error I'm getting on the Rails server when it tries to process this request:

```
Started PUT "/spins/new?auth_token=ZwSp_xJK6nSdjAfUNPev" 
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms
Processing by SpinsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"spin"=>{"project_id"=>44}, "auth_token"=>"ZwSp_xJK6nSdjAfUNPev", "id"=>"new"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Spin with 'id'=new):
```

**I don't know why the Rails app thinks that new is an id parameter - how do I fix this?**

This is my Rails controller:

```
  def new
    @spin = Spin.new(spin_params)
    @spin.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{
        redirect_to edit_project_path(@spin.project)
      }
      format.json{ render :json => @spin, :status => :created, :location => @spin}
    end

  def spin_params
      params.require(:spin).permit(:project_id, :name)
    end
```

**EDIT**

When I use HTTP GET instead (by changing the line: [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];) , I get the following error on my rails server (it seems like the parameters never get passed):

```
Processing by SpinsController#new as JSON
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"ZwSp_xJK6nSdjAfUNPev", "spin"=>{}}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms
Processing by SpinsController#new as JSON
Started GET "/spins/new?auth_token=ZwSp_xJK6nSdjAfUNPev" ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: spin):
app/controllers/spins_controller.rb:117:in `spin_params' app/controllers/spins_controller.rb:16:in `new'
```

Comment: If you are using standard resource routes Rails exepects requests to the new action to be GETs.  Using PUT is routing to the update action.

Comment: thanks for your comment - I also tried using GET but get a different error (the parameters don't seem to be passed)

Comment: You'll make your life easier if you stick with the restful defaults - records are created with post requests to the create action , not put to a new action

Comment: when I try using post, I get the error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/spins/new"):

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the URL I posted to my website - it should not have "new".  It worked when I changed the following line:

```
NSString *newSpinURLString = [spinBaseURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"?auth_token=%@", auth_token];
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer since you figured it out.

Comment: yes, I have to wait a few more hours to accept it (: